# dhcpcd working when its not installed, but doesnt work when its installed

Tags: raspbian

So ive been using dhcpcd all this time without realising that the package isnt installed.
The problem is that the ip on my laptop isn't the same on the raspberry pi (which is hosting an ap). When i install the package and restart the service, it gives me the dhcpcd.service error.

Comment: What error? Please use the [edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/108719/edit) link beneath the question and insert the full error message.

Comment: `dhcpcd` is included with the distribution, so you don't have to install it. As @Ingo suggested, please edit your Q to add the text of your error message. It might also be helpful if you could tell us **how** you installed `dhcpcd` (e.g. `sudo apt-get install dhcpcd`?, or some other way?)